# JavaScript JSON Parse Issue ($.getJSON)

Tags: javascript, json, html

I can't seem to get the following code to output anything to the screen. JavaScript is not my strong suit!

This is the JavaScript code calling a local file that outputs a list of rooms

```
$.getJSON('roomupdate.php?level=1&div=1&callback=json',function(res){
console.log(res.rooms.name[0]);
});
```

In the above I'm merely trying to see the name of the first room in the console. And this is the JSON output (Which I can confirm the script can see and load)

```
json(
{
        "rooms":
        [
            { "name" : "Bedroom" },
            { "name" : "Living Room" },
            { "name" : "Lounge" },
            { "name" : "Kitchen" }
        ]
})
```

Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? Even to view in the console?

Lastly, can you loop through the array?

Comment: You might wanna access your object like `rooms[0].name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON data contains an object `rooms` and this object actually contains an array `[]`, So to access the data inside your array you need to put the index on `rooms` :

```
console.log(res.rooms[0].name);
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this should work but it isn't. I think its my JSON format. It can't be anything else!

Answer (score 1):

Use `callback=?` rather than `callback=json` so that jQuery knows you are using JSONp and can choose it's own name for the callback function.

```
$.getJSON('roomupdate.php?level=1&div=1&callback=?',function(res){
    //alert('Your name is '+res.rooms);

    console.log(res.rooms.name[0]);
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp for details.

Edit:

Looking again, you will need to change the way you are accessing the data around. `res.rooms.name[0]` should be `res.rooms[0].name` because rooms is a list, and each room has a name property.

Comment: Thank you for the info on the callback. I didn't realise it should be ?

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through the array of rooms and log the name of each one:

```
$.each( res.rooms, function( i, room ) {
    console.log( room.name );
});
```

If that doesn't work, then add this statement at the beginning of your callback (where you have the `console.log()` call now):

```
debugger;
```

Load/run your page with the developer tools open, and it will stop in the debugger where you have that statement. Now you can look at all your variables in detail, try out expressions to see what they do, single step through your code, etc.